# Php $_GET issue ( breaking the string after ampersand sign)

Tags: php, urlencode

I am passing an encrypted string in the url and then using php $_GET to retrieve it but i am having some problems with let me write the url first to make it more sense

```
http://localhost/marketplace/test.php?sortid=Cd2&V0reSzN$NBh^tjcF!%3CfsAAhIU%28%3C
```

if you will notice i have an ampersand sign in the middle of the string so when i am echoing out $_GET it is breaking the value after ampersand sign Ex

```
echo $_GET['sortid'];
```

and the result i am getting is Cd2 and it is not reading anything after ampersand sign , the problem i can figure out is that php will read the everything as a different parameter after '&' sign while using $_GET

But i have no idea on how to fix this

Thanks

Comment: http://php.net/urlencode

Comment: This is not a **issue**. You should understand why php (and not only) has this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because ampersand sign has a special meaning in query strings. The behaviour you are experiencing is perfectly normal and expected.

If you want to pass GET parameters that include special characters you should properly encode them using urlencode or alternatively something like base64 encode.

Comment: thanks dude i will encode em properly now... i was sure that ampersand sign has some special meaning , trying to find a way but i believe i should take a better approach then fixing this issue

Comment: You are welcome. If you found answers to your question helpful, please upvote and/or accept them.

Answer (score 0):

by URL creating, replace ampersand with %26, it will do the trick.
Alternately, encode your encoded string with base64 again, then you have no ampersand.